# Cannot open source file in vs code

Tags: c

#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (C:\Users\manth\.vscode\Untitled-1.c)
cannot open source file stdio.h in vs code

Comment: thats very vague, pls elaborate further about your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your includePath doesn't contain any system headers and your compilerPath is set correct and then run C/C++: Log Diagnostics and see if the output appears correct or not.